# Add link label to DataGridView cell or column which is binded to DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

In my project, I'm filling the `dataGridView` from `dataSet` (binding the `DataGridView` to `DataSet`). The first column in `dataGridView` must be `LinkLabels` which I'm trying to get in the below code.

```
dgvMain.DataSorce = ds.Tables[0];
```

I tried: (*not working*)

```
DataGridViewLinkCell lnkCell = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMain.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[0] = lnkCell; // (ERROR) Cell provided already belongs to a grid. This operation is not valid.
}
```

**also tried**

```
for (int intCount = 0; intCount < dgvMain.Rows.Count; intCount++)
{
    dgvMain.Rows[intCount].Cells[0] = lnkCell; // (ERROR) Cell provided already belongs to a grid. This operation is not valid.
}
```

The above attempts are adding `linkLabel` to the first cell only not all the cells in that column
When I debugged my code, I concluded that after adding the `linkLabel` to the first cell exception error is coming which I mentioned in the above code, which is making the code not to run properly.

Please give me any suggestions, what should I do?

**EDIT**:  Though it is not the correct way but I gave the column cells a look like `Linklabel` by writing the below code:

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMain.Rows)
            {
                row.Cells[1].Style.Font = new Font("Consolas", 9F, FontStyle.Underline);
                row.Cells[1].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            }
```

---

Now the problem is that I cant add `Hand` like cursor to the only column cells(which is visible for LinkLabels). Is there anyway to achieve it? (I need answer for both questions, mainly the first one).

Comment: Why don't you add your link in ItemTemplate of GridView in aspx page , And you can find taht control in code behaind easily in ItemDataBound event of GridView..

Comment: This is winforms not asp.net. :)

Comment: Sorry My bad i think it was a web page but you get help from these link  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/3f53e654-3de3-4a88-8e91-6bcd6bf2d3d1 & http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/378991/how-to-add-a-linklable-control-to-a-datagridview#

Comment: Why cant you use the designer to add the linkcolumn? And do you need a cell to sometimes be a link and sometimes not?

Comment: @helgeheldre The cell which I am trying to make should be always a link. I am trying to modify the existing column here which was created because of the Binded DataSet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I've been doing when I'm changing type of the cell. 
Use your "also tried" loop and change:

```
dgvMain.Rows[intCount].Cells[0] = lnkCell;
```

To:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvMain.Rows)
  {
      DataGridViewLinkCell lc =  new DataGridViewLinkCell();
      lc.Value = r.Cells[0].Value;
      dgvMain[0, r.Index] = lc;
  }
```

Second Question:
Set the CellMouseLeave and CellMouseMove of the dgvMain events to the following.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    }
}
```

Comment: dgvMain doesn't have any method like `Item` should I import any namespace?

Comment: @Mr_green. Sorry, I was a bit stuck in VB.NET mindset. This is tested and works

Comment: r is the equivalent of dgvMain.Rows[intCount]

Comment: Ok thank you this works but unfortunately I need answer for the second question too :(. If you know the answer please share

Comment: I think you need to check your code, I made some changes to make it work.

Comment: The Foreach loop should be just fine. The other one has some flaws since i tried to merge my old solution with the new.

Comment: I have just edited your answer which was working for me, hope you dont mind.

Comment: I might have ruined that by editing it myself. But I guess we will find out :)

Comment: Its alright this is also working, I was doing a foolish mistake. Do you know the answer for the second question ? :)

Comment: What is the second question?

Comment: Sorry my bad I haven't higlighted it. It is in `Edit` section of my question. I need to change cursor for only a column cells..

Comment: Yes it did :D. I will mark you as answer for now. after sometime I will give you the bounty too.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry about not getting it right the first time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a new instance of `DataGridViewLinkCell` to *each* "link" cell. Firt change the type of the cells that are links to be a `DataGridViewLinkCell` and then handle the click on the cell, like this:

```
void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (System.Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(r.Cells["Links"].Value.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute))
        {
            r.Cells["Links"] = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
            DataGridViewLinkCell c = r.Cells["Links"] as DataGridViewLinkCell;
        }
    }
}

// And handle the click too
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkCell)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value as string);
    }
}
```